# How to create a Common Custom TableView Class?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to create a custom tableView class, Which can be used in any view Controller. I have to  just create tableview object and set an array and frame of tableview . Then this tableview will be add as subview on my view. and also give me a click event.

I just want to avoid writing tableview datasource and delegate method in every viewController class.

Comment: iDea is good.. but where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a viewController or tableviewController class and code all the delegates and data source methods there. now in you view controller where you want to make it as a subview call the tableview class and add it as a subview.

EX:

```
TableviewContrller *libaray =[TableviewContrller new];
[libaray willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:libaray.view];
[self addChildViewController:libaray];
```

To hide write this code in your tableview controller class

```
[self.view removeFromSuperView];
```

As you are using a reusable class you need to send the array information to that class. along with it it will be better to send either class name or setting tag value to tableview

So in your tableview class write this

```
-(id)initWithInformationArray :(NSMutableArray *)dataArray andTagValueforTableview :(int) tagValue
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", dataArray);
}
return self;
}
```

Now sub viewing will be like this

```
TableviewContrller *libaray =[[TableviewContrller alloc]initWithInformationArray:YOURARRAY andTagValueforTableview:TAGVALUE];
[libaray willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:libaray.view];
[self addChildViewController:libaray];
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use UITableViewController.

UITableViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, when you create a subclass of UITableViewController, the template has the usual methods of tableview datasource and delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a custom class and create your own delegate in that class for UITableView. Now whenever you create a UITableView assign that custom class as the class for UITableView.
If you don't know how to create custom delegates then check below links:

1. http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002
2. http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tip-create-your-own-objective-c-delegate-protocol/

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create BaseTableView class.

```
@interface BaseTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray* listObject;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listObject;

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style;

@end

@implementation BaseTable

@synthesize listObject;

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame style:style])
    {
        self.dataSource = self;
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setListObject:(NSArray *)listObjectRef
{
    [listObject release];
    listObject = [listObjectRef retain];
    [self reloadData];
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [listObject release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Inherit this class for specific use and override following methods according to needs

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

In your ViewController class use following code

```
SpecificTableView *table = [[SpecificTableView alloc] init];
[table setListObject:((FRFTReportList*)obj)];
```

Hopefully this will help.